# Retrieve largest negative number and smallest positive number from list

Tags: python, list, max, min, negative-number

Given a list of integers, e.g.:

```
lst = [-5, -1, -13, -11, 4, 8, 16, 32]
```

is there a Pythonic way of retrieving the largest negative number in the list (e.g. `-1`) and the smallest positive number (e.g. `4`) in the list?

Comment: Where should `0` end up, if present? And don't name your own list `list`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just use list comprehensions:

```
>>> some_list = [-5, -1, -13, -11, 4, 8, 16, 32]
>>> max([n for n in some_list if n<0])
-1
>>> min([n for n in some_list  if n>0])
4
```

Comment: You can also use a generator expression here (and I'd advise against naming it `l`, maybe `lst` -- `l` looks too much like `1` in some fonts.

Comment: OK, I changed the variable name, though it's a bit beside the point for this. To use a generator expression instead change `[]` to `()`. I will leave the list form in the answer so it is clearer to anyone not familiar with it (like anyone with the same question as OP).

Comment: To use a generator expression, you can just drop the `[]` entirely.  e.g. `max(n for n in some_list if n < 0)` which looks a lot cleaner after you've gotten used to it.